# Transferring old HDD to new PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have 2 computers, both run Windows 7. One is very old (I bought it back in 2011) and the other is brand new. Weirdly the HDD of my new PC suddenly stopped working but my very old HDD is still working. So I decided to move my old HDD to my new PC.

If I just plug in my old HDD onto my new PC, will it work?

Comment: It should work all okay. (make sure the non-working hard drive is unplugged from the new PC.)

Comment: @YisroelTech Ok and let's assume it didn't work and I want to put it back to my old PC..will it still work?

Comment: You will loose windows activation if you will try to move old HDD to the new computer and if hardware are different then you will get BSOD on new PC but if you will use `sysprep` on old PC then you can moved it to a new one (I mean no BSOD) but you will loose Windows activation anyway

Comment: @Alex I tried sysprep but I get fatal error and yes hardware is different

Comment: Looks like fastest way in your case is save users files and reinstall OS on new PC then restore users files.

Comment: @Alex you mean format the HDD?

Comment: Yes, just reinstall it. You should have a COA sticker on new PC, so use it to activate new systems. You can officially download Win7 ISO from microsoft for reinstallation

Comment: @Alex Ok i will first try moving it..If i get any errors then I will format it